# What can I do for this site?

Tags: discussion, faq

I really like this site, and want to help it succeed. What can I do for Chemistry-Stack Exchange at this stage of the beta?

Comment: There are plenty of slots in the "Community Bulletin", so do what you think is right.  We don't need the Mod announcement over there any longer, if you want to swap these two.

Answer (score 11):

This is what one can do, in order of preference (from "best thing to do" to "good thing to do")

First and foremost, **vote for good posts**. Voting rewards good posts and encourages users, besides sorting out the best post.

### Advertise advertise advertise

- Tell all who may be interested how awesome this site/network is.
- Encourage colleagues/classmates/friends(who have a background in chem) to join.
- Write an awesome blog post, like [this one by a TW mod](http://www.thickbook.com/2012/02/dear-stackexchange-will-you-be-my-valentine/)
- Add/use suggestions [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131/how-do-we-promote-our-shiny-new-site)
- Try to get more experts engaged.
- Retweet the good questions posted by [@StackChemistry](http://twitter.com/#!/StackChemistry)

### Ask questions

Try to ask good questions. Make them conceptual, thought-provoking, and specific. ([more guidelines here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask))

### Answer stuff

Write [good answers](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) to any question you may find. It doesn't matter if the question is already answered; if you have something already not in the other answers, feel free to add it as a separate answer!

You may use [our unanswered questions](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/unanswered) as a good place to start.

---

Another thing one can do is write blog post-style Question-answer duets ([use the "answer own question" button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132886/what-is-this-answer-your-own-question-jazz)). Try not to do this too often, though--use it if you have something that will be interesting to the majority of the community and extremely informative.

Answer (score 2):

## Good advertisements!

Vote in other SE communities to advertise this one, like in  [Academia SE](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1758/13372) where we can find many academic chemists that can improve this site. So go in the linked page and vote for Chemistry stack exchange ad! The Community ads change every year, so this effort also has to be renewed. If you find a community, which does not yet have an add you can vote on, feel free to post it yourself. After the graduation of our site, a meta thread developed, to keep some track of that: [Posting "Community Promotion" onto other SE sites](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2712/).
[image]

## Good content!

Community should post some good big-list question, a [good big-list question](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291/can-we-make-a-big-list-community-question-for-structure-drawing-software) about software or books can gives visibility, hence new users from chemical world. And be very useful!

## Be gentle with new users!

Speak with the user before downvoting, try to remember that even simple questions are important maybe in the future there will be **Chemical research S.E.**  or other pro S.E. site like math.overflow or [programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), for expert chemists this is not the case for the moment.