# Resources for learning Chemistry

Tags: discussion, faq-proposed, big-list, resources

Recently I saw a post in the german stackexchange, that was about [Resources for learning German](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9526/resources-for-learning-german). And then I asked myself, if it could be possible to make such a post for chemistry, too. It has previously been discussed [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/291/).

The post on the main site is a **community wiki** and contains resources for learning chemistry, like websites, books, etc. that can later on be used as a reference for many answers or comments. It is locked to only allow the answers that have been created in the template to be edited. No new answers can be added.

This is also where this post comes into play. The basic outline of the big list can be found [below](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2913/). It shall contain the most recent state that is going to be in the main post.
If you have questions or suggestions, please leave an answer here.
During the planning phase, this post could have been edited by everyone (> 100 rep) to include, remove or refine items. If you agree with the contents you can still leave a vote. If you disagree please *add a new answer* (so that this post get bumped on the active tab).

**The actual post can now be found [on the main site](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37303/resources-for-learning-chemistry).**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [categories](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/37303/) are currently:

- **(Text)Books:** All books that teach you chemistry with theory and exercises. The subcategories are:

  1. [General Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/37306/)
  2. [Inorganic, Organic and Physical Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/37305/)
  3. [Analytical, Computational, Theoretical and Biochemistry / Chemical Biology](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/37304/)
     *You can add any subcategory to this post if it is missing.*
- [**Online courses and Websites:**](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/37307/) Free or paid services online that teach you chemistry through lessons as well as sites that give help for learning chemistry. They give material, tips, hints, and various help for self-learners or regular students.
- [**Software:**](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/37880/) This can be any software ranging from plugins for the browser over mobile apps up to standalone applications for the computer. Pure 2D or 3D visualization programs as well as quantum chemistry programs might not fit in this category, as they are not primarily focused on teaching chemistry.
- [**Video Resources & TV:**](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/37310/) Video resources which help learning chemistry.

*Currently those are all categories. If you think, that a new one should be added, please submit an answer in the corresponding [meta thread](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/37304/). (A comment is probably not sufficient, as it does "bump" the question on the* active *tab.*

Answer (score 3):

Currently the thread is disorganised, so below are a couple of thoughts on how to improve it:

1. There are two different kinds of grouping here: by the type of a resource (book, video, website, etc.) and by the branch of chemistry the resource is about (general, organic, computational, etc.) So let us decide first on the overall structure of the thread: **shall we group resources in accordance with their type first and then by branches or other way around**? To illustrate these choices (of which I prefer the second):

   **Choice 1**

   - Books

     - General chemistry
     - Organic chemistry
     - ...
   - Videos

     - General chemistry
     - Organic chemistry
     - ...
   - ...

   **Choice 2**

   - General chemistry

     - Books
     - Videos
     - ...
   - Organic chemistry

     - Books
     - Videos
     - ...
   - ...
2. Then I think it's a good idea to have **one answer per each category of the first order**. I would prefer the second of the above mentioned grouping schemes, so that we will have one answer for general chemistry resource, one for organic chemistry, etc.
3. I think it is fine (and should be even encouraged) if we write a **small description of each resource**, not just state its level (beginner, intermediate, or advanced). As an example take a look at [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) at SO. It is also a good idea to link some **reviews** (both from journals and bookstores like Amazon) if available.

Comment: We were faster :O ... if the majority thinks like this, we might have to change it.

Comment: In principle I would also have preferred your second choice. Unfortunately this comes with the disadvantage, that if there is no category for let's say Polymer Chemistry (which we did not think about) the post has to be unlocked, the answer has to be created, the post has to be locked again. In the version we choose, resources can easily be added to any section, without the need to unlock everything. I very much agree on your third point and hence added "For the resources, a short summary is very much appreciated." to the main post.