# Addition of nomenclature to the resources page?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Would be a section «organic nomenclature» suitable for the [resources](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37303/resources-for-learning-chemistry) page?

On occasion, there are questions about naming organic structures.  Prompted by an edit of an answer about organic nomenclature [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/154185/iupac-naming-for-a-ring-system-containing-different-ring-structures), the exhaustive answer refers to the 2013 edition of IUPAC's [Blue Book](https://iupac.org/what-we-do/books/bluebook/) which may be purchased in print, or as electronic resource. There is a [sibling site](https://www.qmul.ac.uk/sbcs/iupac/BlueBook/) claiming to mirror the content of the rules, and a separate [*Brief Guide*](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/pac-2019-0104/html).

Because our university did not (yet) invest into either one of the two former, I can't say a iota about the first three references.  Regardless that there are programs trying to facilitate the structure2name conversion, there is no dedicated entry on «Resources learning Chemistry» to address this part of chemical education either.

Since it isn't a real text book, (video) course, nor software, would be such an additional sub-section suitable?

At present, I think such a section should include a hint to the Blue Book as *the* source, however equally point to the content mirrored at Queen Mary University (for the detail) as well as the *Brief Guide* (for the polychromic illustrations).  What do you think about the inclusion of a reference *like* [ChemDraw's sample page][6] which includes a structure2name and name2structure function?  Are there other sample pages (e.g., Marvin Sketch, Chemdoodle / chemdoodle webcomponents) with similar / complementary functionality to mention?  E.g., Chemdoodle desktop allows the user some adjustment which (sub-)set of rules to use to convert a structure plot into *a* name; on the other hand, their relevant [test page][7] constrains the number of conversions.

Suggesting such a sub-section about nomenclature, I speculate hinting the reader to the other color books (red [inorganic], orange [analytical], purple [macromolecular chemistry], green [quantities / symbols physical chemistry]) and the Gold Book by IUPAC / the compilation by IUCr about [crystallography](https://www.iucr.org/resources/commissions/crystallographic-nomenclature) would be welcome if brief pointing to the book (like for the other text books) and on-line register (where available).

What is your perspective about this?

Answer (score 8):

*Note: This answer reflects the old status quo, an additional answer was introduced.*

As of now the gold book is in the Websites category. Same goes for some works about crystallography. As a quick fix, I'd propose the same here, i.e. mentioning the online resource and including a citation to the original there.

This is how we arranged it a couple years back, and this answer is only suggesting to use this structure for the time being.

It might be time to revisit this structure and I am open for this; this answer must not deter this discussion.

For more context: [Resources for learning Chemistry](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2889/4945)

Answer (score 1):

I have moved the additions Buttonwood already made into a new answer, which can be extended quite freely now:

- [**References about Nomenclature:**](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/155812/) Successful communication requires an agreed set of definitions compiled as nomenclature. An example for such compilations are IUPAC's Color Books, named by the color of their book cover.