# Posting "Community Promotion" onto other SE sites

Tags: discussion

I think we should promote our newly-graduated site on other StackExchange sites.

I'd advocate posting an ad on:

- [Physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/community-promotion-ads-2015)
- [Academia](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1478/community-promotion-ads-2015)

Any other suggestions? The sites would already need to be graduated to have community-promotion ads linking to our site.

Comment: Once there's a bit of feedback on the ad graphic, I'd be happy to go post on Physics, Academia, etc.

Comment: I had the same idea, but i want more colour. We have shiny green and beakers and stuff, i want that, too. ;)

Comment: @Martin-マーチンFeel free to take mine and modify or take your own. That's my hope for this thread.

Comment: Or add molecules and orbitals? Heck, maybe we have more than one ad. :-)

Comment: [I posted it on physics](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/community-promotion-ads-2015/6789#6789)!

Comment: how about on the math forum

Comment: [I posted it on academia!](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/1758/13372)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There has been a [change to the sidebar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272563/were-standardizing-the-sidebar-width-at-300px-on-all-sites), so there was a need to create a new version.
It took me some time and only because they allowed the file size to be [150 kB
 again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/273271/260760) it was possible.

[image: Haikus are awesome/ Chemistry is more so/ Ask straight away!]

If you want to post it anywhere, simply use the following code:

```
[![Haikus are awesome/ Chemistry is more so/ Ask straight away!][1]][2]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/noaFv.png
  [2]: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com
```

If you want to temper with the layered source, find it at [deviantart](http://sirconrade.deviantart.com/art/Main-ad-dev3-585373559).

I have since posted it (as community wiki) to

- [academia.se](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2170/13372)
- [physics.se](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7468/104362)
- [biology.se](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3299/21206)

If you have a vote to spare, or would like to change the add, do so.

---

*For consistency, the old post is included:*

Since I complained about the proposed image, I have to give it a try myself. I love how we have a very bright and colourful theme, *because we are a very colourful and bright science*, so I wanted to reflect that. In response to the comments, I changed the font to a 100% free font: [quicksand](http://www.dafont.com/quicksand.font?fpp=100&af=on&psize=s&l[]=10&l[]=1&text=CHEMISTRY.STACKEXCHANGE.COM), which needed a little tweaking. I also changed the white box to a 5% grey, making it a little bit softer on the eye.

[image: Haikus are awesome/ Chemistry is more so/ Ask straight away!]

Old version using [verdana](http://www.fonts.com/de/font/microsoft-corporation/verdana), which is a non-free font: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2pJJ.png
Alternate version bye Geoff using [Avenir Condensed Bold](http://www.fonts.com/de/font/linotype/avenir-next/condensed-bold), which is also a non-free font: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtUhL.png
Here's a modified version by Molx with the same general layout, but a purple-ish table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dz3um.png

In case anyone would like to go and play with the original (layered) source, you can download a zipped xcf file for [gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) at [<s>tinyupload</s> deviantart](http://sirconrade.deviantart.com/art/Chem-ad-585372166).

Comment: I think it would be better if the bottom text box with the URL has a greenish background rather than a white one to match it with the green Chem.SE theme.

Comment: @BinaryGeek I tried to implement the table idea of [Kurtis' original design](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/chemistry-site-design#comment1407_1673).

Comment: the font looks slightly odd on that picture, but I like the general idea! maybe turn the white into a splotchy gray? the lab bench is being used after all ;)

Comment: I agree, the font is odd, I just picked verdana since it was the least odd I found in my library. I could put any other font there if I am able to get it. Please make suggestions.

Comment: I tried Avenir Condensed Bold here: http://i.imgur.com/TfLF0Gj.png

Comment: Here's a modified version with the same general layout: http://i.imgur.com/MXg3kLA.png

Comment: I have included it in the post. I personally don't really like the purple table it feels unresting to me.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン any suggested color? Or any other change, for that matter.

Comment: @Molx Well, I like it just the way I made it. So I cannot really comment on that, sorry.

Comment: Martin, can we ask you to update this for the 2016 sizes? Community ads now need to be 300x250, or ideally 600x500 if the filesize allows ([150kb](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/273271/184688)). I'm happy to delve in myself, but the .xcf link is broken.

Comment: @E.P. I'm on it. I stopped working on it because of the file size reduction, but now that they give us more, it seems possible again.

Comment: Excellent. Ping me here if you want me to post it on Physics, but it's probably better if you do - and that way I can upvote you ;-).

Comment: @E.P. You may upvote now ;)

Comment: Can I ask where you got the background and other design elements, by the way? They're surprisingly hard to extract, and this one plainly doesn't come from the banner anyway.

Comment: @E.P. Last year I spent some time meandering though the source code. I had to analyse the  whole shabang - they were not easy to find. But chrome does a well enough job when you inspect the page, like highlighting and so on... and eventually you find what you are looking for. I had, however, no idea that its layered that much.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there are many sites which have chemistry as tag, so I think we should specially cover all sites which have [chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chemistry) or about science.

- biology
- [H.S.M](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/)
- [Earth Science](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/)

  ---

P.S.  All the above sites are still in Beta stage

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the sites Geoff has offered.  I would suggest we also advertise on:

- [Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) (note: they are still in beta)
- [Biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/)
- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)

Computational science may have occasional overlap with computational chemistry.  Biology is a no-brainer. Stack Overflow would reach a wider, albeit, less targeted audience.

Comment: Can we advertise on beta sites? I thought they didn't have community ads yet.

Comment: @GeoffHutchison Possibly not but certainly something to keep in mind when they go out of beta.

Comment: Bio has graduated.