# Vote to Promote (Cross Site Community Promotion Ads)

Tags: discussion

To rehash an older point([Posting "Community Promotion" onto other SE sites](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2712/posting-community-promotion-onto-other-se-sites)), I want to encourage people to vote on Chem SE community ads on other Stack sites. We currently have ads posted to [Biology](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3890/community-promotion-ads-2019), [Physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11001/community-promotion-ads-2019?cb=1), and [Academia](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/community-promotion-ads-2019). I think these sites have the most overlap with ours and we would benefit from attracting users from these sites. Feel free to suggest any other sites that might be good to post the ad or any changes to the ad itself.

Comment: Just one more vote needed on Academia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use the version with the correct size as it is given in the linked thread.

```
[![Haikus are awesome/ Chemistry is more so/ Ask straight away!][1]][2]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/noaFv.png
  [2]: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com
```

[image: Haikus are awesome/ Chemistry is more so/ Ask straight away!]

Comment: This is the version I posted on Academia, but on Biology they said it was too big so I used the old version which seemed to be smaller. I think it should be the right size, but I didn't know for sure at the time and didn't want to argue with them over something I didn't know.

Comment: This is the correct size, the old one definitely won't make it into rotation. I wouldn't sweat it on biology though, I don't think they like to promote our site, or anything for that matter, given that only one reached the threshold last year...